# child class not able to access parent member

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have created a variable in base class that is a vector of template but I'm not able to access this member from the derived class , can someone explain?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
template <typename T>
class Apple{
protected:
public:
    vector<T> vec;
    virtual void foo(T node) =0;
};

template <typename T>
class Ball:public Apple<T>{
public:
    void foo(T node){
        cout<<"hahaha\n";
        vec.push_back(node);/* I GET COMPILATION ERROR HERE"vec was not declared in this scope"*/
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Ball<int> b;
    b.foo(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I GET COMPILATION ERROR HERE" - is the error not shared because you don't want us to know what it is?

Comment: it's not private use `this->vec`

Comment: Code posted compiles fine.  I'm flagging as not reproducible.

Comment: This [might](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members) be helpful, but I don't think it applies since `vec` is a dependent name.

Comment: @UKMonkey I can't compile this with either [GCC 7.2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IXnG95It6yklM1Kk) or [Clang 5.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zhj611bNcZCi42Tp) (Copy/Pasted exactly as is). On what compiler is this working?

Answer (score 3):

The member `vec` is of a template parameter [dependent type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) so the compiler needs some help like:

```
this->vec.push_back(node);
```

or use qualified name:

```
Apple<T>::vec.push_back(node)
```

Thanks to @Avran Borborah - [Why am I getting errors when my template-derived-class uses a member it inherits from its template-base-class?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members)

> Here’s the rule: the compiler does not look in dependent base classes (like `B<T>`) when looking up nondependent names (like `f`).
>
> This doesn’t mean that inheritance doesn’t work. ...

Comment: Why should we give scope resolution here ,Is that because I'm using template class??

Comment: Yes, look at the link @Avran Borborah posted - [Why am I getting errors when my template-derived-class uses a member it inherits from its template-base-class?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members)

Answer (score 0):

You have not created any private members in the base class.
To resolve the error, you can replace the line which produces compilation error with :
Apple::vec.push_back(node);
or
this->vec.push_back(node)